# Python - is there a way to implement __getitem__ for multidimension array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I would like use something like that:

```
class Board():
    ...
    def __getitem__(self, y, x):
        return self.board[y][x]
```

but unfortunatelly, when I call:

```
board[x][y]
```

I get:
`TypeError: __getitem__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you do `board[x][y]` you will cause *two* calls to `__getitem__` because you are doing two separate accesses: `[x]` is one and `[y]` is another.  There's no way to handle this directly in `__getitem__`; you'd have to have `board[x]` return some kind of sub-object that you could use `[y]` on to get the individual item.  What you probably want is to have `__getitem__` accept a tuple:

```
def __getitem__(self, tup):
    y, x = tup
    return self.board[y][x]
```

Then do:

```
board[x, y]
```

(Note that you have the order of x and y switched between `__getitem__` and `board[x][y]` --- is that intentional?)

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for as a helper class for working with worksheets.  I wanted to address either by column number or by name and this allows me to pass row and column together with minimum syntax overhead.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to consider using this syntax:

```
board[(x, y)]
```

It's less pretty, but it allows you to have multidimensional arrays simply. Any number of dimensions in fact:

```
board[(1,6,34,2,6)]
```

By making board a defaultdict you can even have sparse dictionaries:

```
board[(1,6,34,2,6)]

>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> board = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
>>> board[(1,6,8)] = 7
>>> board[(1,6,8)]
7
>>> board[(5,6,3)]
0
```

If you want something more advanced than that you probably want [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: way late in the game here, but  the parens are unnecessary, as comma is the tuple operator not the parens.   the defaultdict thing is way cool though.

Answer (score 4):

`board[x][y]` means `board.__getitem__(x).__getitem__(y)`, so `Board.__getitem__` has to return some kind of view that also supports `__getitem__` and remembers `x`. This is a bit of work, but for some use cases (anything involving passing that view around) it's very convenient.

Another option is `board[x, y]`, which means `board.__getitem__((x, y))`. Note that this passes a tuple to `__getitem__`, which you'll have to unpack manually (there is syntactic sugar for doing this in 2.x, but it's a bit obscure and also gone in 3.x, so you may want to avoid it in the interest of future porting work).

Answer (score 4):

Just do:

```
class Board():
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return self.board[x]
```

because when you call `b[x][y]` it actually calls `__getitem__()` twice, as showed below:

```
import numpy as np
b = Board()
b.board = np.random.random((3,3,3))
print (b[2][0]==(b[2])[0]).all()
#True
```

But the best would be to subclass `np.ndarray`, so that you don't have to re-implement this method:

```
class Board(np.ndarray):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I think indexing a 2D custom object can be done with state retention.

As mentioned in the posts above, 2D indexing into a custom object will call `__getitem__()` twice.  If `__getitem__()` can be made to remember that it returned a row of the board in the first call, it can return the column value in the second call.

```
def __getitem__(self, item):

    def get(id):
        # This is the first time get() is being called,
        # return the row indexed by item
        if not get.row:
            get.row = self.board[item]
            return get.row
        else:
        # This is the second time get() is called,
        # return the column in the row indexed by item
            return get.row[item]

    # Set the function attribute "row". 
    # This is used to remember if get() was called once before.
    get.row = None
    return get(item)
```

Comment: But that wouldn't work. You would need the caller to never ever use 1d indexing, or else you are shifted... (not to mention multithread, even if that is theoretical since GIL would protect you with current python implementation). Besides, it is not really what was meant by that "2 calls to getimem". It is 2 calls, but not on the same object.

Answer (score -1):

Say b is the class object b = Board(). When you are looking for `B[0][0]` `__getitem__` won't normally work. Instead what we can do is set b's data equal to a new variable.

```
boardData = b.data

print(boardData[0][0])
```